# Возможно ли написать конвертер в JPEG на JS?

Tags: javascript, jpeg

Появилась необходимость для веб-приложения сделать конвертер PNG или других форматов в JPEG. Раньше с таким не сталкивался, поэтому, возникает вопрос: возможно ли написать конвертер в JPEG на JavaScript?

Comment: Возможно, Вам поможет этот пост. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20744628/how-to-convert-a-image-from-png-to-jpeg-using-javascript

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, очень помогли)

Answer (score 0):

Да, возможно. Также можно попробовать конвертировать в WebAssembly готовые нативные реализации.